# How do I delete an AWS resource by ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a service-linked role in AWS that I need to delete.  When I try to delete it in IAM it fails and has a popup with the ARNs of two resources that use this role.  This [brain-dead blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/now-use-aws-iam-to-delete-a-service-linked-role-when-you-no-longer-require-an-aws-service-to-perform-actions-on-your-behalf/) shows me the steps to recreate the problem I'm having and tells me that I need to delete the resources that use the role I'm trying to delete.  Duh.

I've tried searching the given ARNs in the IAM search window, but it doesn't find them.

Now that I have the ARNs, how can I delete them so I can delete this role?

Comment: According to my answer - if you will provide that ARNs (you can mask AWS account id/region/resource id - only service and resourcetype/resource part is important - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-arns) - I can prepare commands for delete that resources or give advices on how delete them from UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API that provide delete of any resource by any ARN. You need to use specific services for delete resources.

If you have ARNs - according to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-arns) - it will be 3rd part (by "**:**" character):

```
arn:partition:SERVICE:region:account-id... // SERVICE where your resource is present
```

For example - if you have that ARN:

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:1234567890:instance/i-12345678901234567
```

That indicates it's EC2 instance. You can delete it via AWS Console (UI) or by example using [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html):

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids i-12345678901234567
```

**EDIT**

According to link you provided ([brain-dead blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/now-use-aws-iam-to-delete-a-service-linked-role-when-you-no-longer-require-an-aws-service-to-perform-actions-on-your-behalf/)) there are ARNs of Redshift clusters, so you can try delete them via [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/delete-cluster.html) using this command:

```
aws --region <REGION> redshift delete-cluster --cluster-identifier <CLUSTER ID>
```

Where *REGION* and *CLUSTER ID* you can obtain from ARNs.

If you want to delete them from UI (AWS Console) - don't forget change to proper region.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I was deleting a RDS instance so the command is `aws --region us-east-1 rds delete-db-instance --db-instance-identifier nd3io3zfxyzxyz --skip-final-snapshot`